# How to disable cache in odata v2 model sapui5

Tags: odata, sapui5

oData v2 model has the feature to cache the used data and read data. I want to disable the cache feature. I don't want to keep the data in my model. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable cache. But you also don't really need to.

If you're afraid that the cached data is old, just use the `refresh` method to get the model to retrieve new data from the server. When you execute the `refresh` method, each binding reloads its data from the server. For list or element bindings, a new request to the backend is triggered.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know about this refresh but i do not want to cache the data in my model.Anyway, I came to know that there is no way to clear the model cache.